# How to get CanCan to only allow user to view their own profile in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

In `ability.rb` I have the following statements:

```
if user.is_employee?
  can :schedule, Employee, id: user.employee.id
end
```

This should allow employees to view their own schedule at `/employees/273/schedule`. That URL will work if the employee's id is 273. This works... an employee is able to view that URL. The problem is employees can view ***all*** other ids as well. Shouldn't the above limit employees to only schedule their own id?

***UPDATE***: Here's my `EmployeeController`:

```
class EmployeeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  authorize_resource
  def schedule
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: show your controller please

Comment: @apneadiving - I posted the controller in the question

Comment: you need to load and authorize the resource if you want to check conditions on it

Comment: I do have `authorize_resource` there, I thought `load_and_authorize` simply did the additional step of loading the resource.

Comment: authorize needs the resource, so either you prepend a before filter to do it yourself or you use load_and_authorize

Answer (score 1):

remove `authorize_resource` from controller and add`authorize! :schedule, @employee` after `@employee = Employee.find(params[:id])`

your controller

```
class EmployeeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def schedule
   @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
   authorize! :schedule, @employee
  end
end
```

then in your ability.rb...

```
if user.is_employee?
 can :schedule, Employee do |emp|
   user.employee.id == emp.id
 end
end
```